# How to upload paid application in android market

Tags: android, google-play

I developed one android application.I need to upload it on android market as a paid version. I have publisher account in android market . How can i do it ?

Do I need any change in my application code ? What is 'Application Licensing' ? Is it need for paid application to upload in market ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to have 2 different version of your app and name them slightly different.  For example MyApp and MyApp Free.

Here's the official documentation for uploading to the market:  http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/publishing.html

Here's the documentation on Application Licensing. http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/licensing.html